# No instance for (Show ([(Char, Char)] -> Char))

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghci

So I have to make a function that finds a pair with its 1st letter and returning the 2nd letter.

I actually found one answer but with the map function and I couldn't get it.

```
      lookUp :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char
      lookUp x [] = x
      lookUp x ( ( st,nd ): rst) | st == x = nd
                   | otherwise = lookUp x rst
```

And I get this message:

```
No instance for (Show ([(Char, Char)] -> Char))
arising from a use of `print'
 Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Show ([(Char, Char
  In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to supply all the arguments at the ghci prompt, eg

```
lookUp 'c' [('b','n'), ('c','q')]
```

Should give you 'q'.

It's complaining that it can't show a function. Any time it says it doesn't 
have a Show instance for something with -> in, it's complaining it can't 
show a function. It can only show the result of using the function on some data.

When you give it some, but not all data, Haskell interprets that as a new function 
that takes the next argument, so

```
lookUp 'c'
```

is a function that will take a list of pairs of characters and give you a character.
That's what it was trying to show, but couldn't.

By the way, almost every time you get a "No instance for..." error, it's because 
you did something wrong with the arguments - missed some out, put them in 
the wrong order. The compiler's *trying* to be helpful by suggesting you add 
an instance, but probably you just need to check you supplied the write type 
of arguments in the right order.

Have fun learning Haskell!

Comment: ...and ignore the "possible fix" as well!

Comment: Indeed it would seem very much more helpful if GHC changed the "possible fix" suggestion to "function needs more arguments" or something, at least for that specific case. After all, you don't that often make function types instances of any typeclass, if at all than usually just one parameter of a MultiParamTypeClass.

Comment: One problem is that currying is used quite often in Haskell, especially if you like to write point-free expressions.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you typed something like this in ghci:

```
*Main> lookUp 'c'
```

An expression like `lookUp 'c'` is a partial evaluation / curried form of the `lookUp` function. It's type is:

```
*Main> :t lookUp 'c'
lookUp 'c' :: [(Char, Char)] -> Char
```

which is the exact type that ghci says there is no Show instance for.

To test your function, be sure to supply both `x` and the the list of `Char` pairs:

```
*Main> lookUp 'c' [ ('a','A'), ('b','B'), ('c','C') ]
'C'
```